# Как я могу сделать сцену неактивной?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я подгружаю сцены аддиктивно и проблема в том ,что у меня работают две сцены сразу:
Начальная(которая должна быть всегда) и сцена загруженная аддиктивно.
Нужно что бы начальную игрок не видел.

Comment: а открыть 3 сцены, в т.ч. первую пустой пробовал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сцену нельзя сделать неактивной только [выгрузить](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.UnloadScene.html) . Можно скрыть отдельные объекты, но для этого придется покодить немножко.